# Solve recurrence equation: $a_{n}=(n-1)(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Find and solve recurrence equation $a_{n}$, where $a_{n}$ is the number of derangement in permutation $\pi\in S_{n}$, and $\forall_{i\in \mathbb{N}_{n}}\pi(i)\ne i$.
I managed to find the equation:
$$
a_{n} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$ = 0} \\
0, & \text{if $n$ = 1}  \\
(n-1)(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}), & \text{if $n\ge2$}
\end{cases},
$$
but I don't know how to solve it. Only managed to get to this:
$A(x) = 1+\sum^\infty_{n=0}{(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n+2}}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}{(n+1)a_{n}x^{n+2}}$.

Comment: Try writing $b_n=\frac{a_n}{(n-1)!}$ and then express your recurrence in terms of $b_n$ by dividing both sides of $a_n=(n-1)(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$ through by $(n-1)!$ and simplifying; this will give a slightly easier recurrence relation.

Comment: Do you see the opportunity to apply inverse of derivative?

Comment: Will try that, Steven.

Comment: rtybase, you mean to integrate the equation? I could try that but I don't see yet how it'll help me.

Answer (score -1):

the solution is given by the Gamma-function, $$a(n)=\frac{\Gamma (n+1,-1)-\Gamma
   (2,-1) \Gamma (n+1)}{e-\Gamma
   (2,-1)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think I'll help me.

Comment: That's a very interesting solution. Could you elaborate the derivation? I tried comparing it numerically to the original sequence and got the same results.